# CSS3 animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

This one is a bit of a long shot but here goes - I'm new to css3 animation so please bare with..

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJyomx)

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").mmenu({
     extensions  : [ "theme-dark", "effect-slide-menu", "effect-slide-listitems" ],
     iconPanels : {
      add   : true,
      visible  : 1,
      hideNavbars : true
     }
     
     })
    
 
  
  
         $("#hamburger").click(function(){
            $(".burger .one, .burger .two, .burger  .three, .circle").css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "running");
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
          <div class="header">
             
         <a href="#menu" id="hamburger">

       <div class="burger">
         <div class="one"></div>
         <div class="two"></div>
         <div class="three"></div>
       </div>
     
       <div class="circle"></div>
    
    </a>
             Demo
          </div>
          <div class="content">
             <p><strong>This is a demo.</strong><br />
                Click the menu icon to open the menu.</p>
          </div>
       </div>
      
      <!-- The page End-->
      
     <!-- The menu -->
    <nav id="menu">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="/about">About us</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
                   <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

When the hamburger menu opens the animation starts on the icon but then when you close it the animation stays at the open state. I want it to return to the original state

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJyomx codepen link

Answer (score 0):

Use the mousedown event of the mm-blocker to reset the previous style. I used animation direction reverse to do it. Here's the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpoPqQ

```
     $("#mm-blocker").on( "mousedown",function(){
     $(".burger .one, .burger .two, .burger  .three, .circle").css("-webkit-animation-direction", "normal");
    } );


        $("#hamburger").click(function(){
        $(".burger .one, .burger .two, .burger  .three, .circle").css("-webkit-animation-direction", "reverse");
        $(".burger .one, .burger .two, .burger  .three, .circle").css("-webkit-animation-direction", "running");

       });
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for this its a great help. the only issue im haveing now is the animation on opening isnt working , any ideas??